# React-native Cant find package android.support.v7.app

Tags: android, react-native, build.gradle

I'm having this really annoying error that wont let me build...
It says it cant find the package android.support.v7.app
With errors all over my SplashScreen js file

```
error: package android.support.v7.app does not exist
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
                             ^
D:\FifaLeagueApp\FifaIL\android\app\src\main\java\com\fifail\SplashActivity.java:7: error: cannot find symbol
public class SplashActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
                                ^
```

I'll provide my gradles (I think the problem coming from them but I cant figure what exactly causing it)

```
// Top-level build file where you can add configuration options common to all sub-projects/modules.

buildscript {
    ext {
        buildToolsVersion = "28.0.3"
        minSdkVersion = 16
        compileSdkVersion = 28
        targetSdkVersion = 28
        supportLibVersion = "28.0.0"
    }
    repositories {
        google()
        jcenter()
    }
    dependencies {
        classpath('com.android.tools.build:gradle:3.4.2')
        // NOTE: Do not place your application dependencies here; they belong
        // in the individual module build.gradle files
    }
}
}
```

---

```
...

android {
    compileSdkVersion rootProject.ext.compileSdkVersion

    compileOptions {
        targetCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
        sourceCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
    }
...
    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.fifail"
        minSdkVersion rootProject.ext.minSdkVersion
        targetSdkVersion rootProject.ext.targetSdkVersion
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"
    }
 ...

dependencies {
    implementation project(':react-native-vector-icons')
    implementation project(':react-native-splash-screen')
    implementation project(':react-native-restart')
    implementation project(':react-native-gesture-handler')
    implementation fileTree(dir: "libs", include: ["*.jar"])
    implementation 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:28.0.0'
    implementation "com.facebook.react:react-native:+"  // From node_modules
}
....
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Finally fixed the issue, posting solution here for the ones who came here looking for the solution like me:

Just change the imports to following:
[image]

Cheers

Answer (score -1):

sounds like you have enabled AndroidX

check your android/gradle.properties and disable this

```
useAndroidX=true
```

to

```
useAndroidX=false
```

If this is enabled it skips appcompat v7

EDIT: if you need AndroidX do what i mentioned above and add to your android/app/build.gradle a new version of appcompat

```
implementation 'androidx.appcompat:appcompat:${rootProject.ext.supportLibVersion}'
```

and on android/build.gradle

```
supportLibVersion = '1.0.0'
```

Comment: `supportLibVersion = "1.0.0"` and why not `supportLibVersion = "28.0.0"`?

Comment: because its androidX and the version applies to that

Comment: And what about other libraries dependent on that

Comment: but that's the point if you are on the latest version of RN you will have to have updated versions. Do you have a specific problem with what i am referring to or is it just hypothetical